# How to do python SSH tunelling with 2FA?

Tags: python, ssh-tunnel, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to write a python script that connects to a database, but that database is only accessible if you first SSH to a bastion host. From the command-line, this is what I have to do to setup the tunnel:

```
$ ssh -i /path/to/my/key/file.pem -A -L 3307:mydb1.fsd23rqr.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 my_ssh_username1@my-bastion-host.without.2fa
[ec2-user@ip-X-X-X-X ~]$
```

I have created a python script using this [**sshtunnel library**](https://pypi.org/project/sshtunnel/) to do the same thing. It works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import MySQLdb as db
import pandas as pd

print('\nAbout to try connecting')
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('my-ssh-host.without.2fa', 22),
    ssh_username='my_ssh_username1',
    ssh_pkey='/path/to/my/key/file.pem',
    remote_bind_address=('mydb1.fsd23rqr.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com', 3306),
    local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 3307)
) as tunnel:
    print "Connection Established"
    print pd.read_sql_query(
        "select 'Hello' from dual",
        db.connect(
            host='127.0.0.1',
            port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
            user='my_db_username1',
            passwd='****************',
            db='my_db_instance_1'
        )
    )
```

Produces:

```
About to try connecting
Connection Established
   Hello
0  Hello
```

But now I need to use a different DB and bastion combination. This bastion has 2-factor-authentication (2FA) setup so that when I ssh to it, It asks me which method of 2FA I choose. If I choose method #1, it sends a push notification to my android phone which I have to approve:

```
$ ssh -i /path/to/my/key/rsa -A -L 3307:mydb2.fsd23rqr.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 my_ssh_username2@my-bash-host.with.2fa
Duo two-factor login for my_ssh_username2

Enter a passcode or select one of the following options:

 1. Duo Push to XXX-XXX-9671
 2. Phone call to XXX-XXX-9671
 3. SMS passcodes to XXX-XXX-9671 (next code starts with: 1)


Passcode or option (1-3): 1

<WAIT FOR ME TO CLICK APPROVE ON MY ANDROID>

Success. Logging you in...
[my_ssh_username2@ip-X-X-X-1X ~]$
```

But when I try to setup the tunnel using sshtunnel the exact same way to the 2FA-enabled bastion it fails:

```
About to try connecting
Connection Established
Enter DB password:
2018-08-29 15:31:43,985| ERROR   | Could not establish connection from ('127.0.0.1', 3307) to remote side of the tunnel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  <stack-trace snipped>
  File "python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0")
```

How can I write a python script to connect to a Mysql DB through an SSH-tunnel if sshing to that host requires 2FA??

Comment: No help on python, but for the ssh side, can you establish a tunnel via private key only IF you don't spawn a shell on the other end?  Might want to experiment with the `-f` and `-N` options for ssh to find out, and if so, look at re-implementing that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup an interactive SSH session in order to input the options provided by the 2fa enabled server. Having a brief look at the code for the `sshtunnel` library - it seems like they use the `paramiko` [library](http://www.paramiko.org/) to connect to the gateway as well as setup a tunnel. The methods implementing both of these do not have an option for providing an interactive `tty` for user input.

For example, the method performing gateway connection says this:

```
def _connect_to_gateway(self):
    Open connection to SSH gateway
     - First try with all keys loaded from an SSH agent (if allowed)
     - Then with those passed directly or read from ~/.ssh/config
     - As last resort, try with a provided password
```

As you can see, there is no option to perform interactive ssh session commands here.

So your options are to either extend the code using `paramiko` to set up an interactive session, or write your own code using `paramiko` to manage both the gateway connection and tunnel setup. For example `paramiko` provide [this example](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/interactive.py) to perform interactive sessions.